# Call a function from external PHP in Controller codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to create external php file with function in it. How to call the function from controller ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create php comman function file so create your file in application/library folder and add your file in autoload.php in library and you can use any ware

Comment: I did it but i receive error csrf_token. SyntaxError. Unexpected token in JSON at position ...

Comment: Hi, i know why error, it's because i tried to echo in function from external php. It's hit security csrf token issue. Thank you